# Is there a way to ignore spaces in html when I save data frame using to_html?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe

I have '\n' after > and spaces before <. Is there a way to don't save them when I call to_html method?
I have:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
```

I want to have:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe"><thead><tr style="text-align: right;">
```

I tried `escape=False`, `sparsify=True`, `justify='center'` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try package [`minify-html`](https://pypi.org/project/minify-html/):

```py
from minify_html import minify

import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": [1, 1, 1, 1],
        "b": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "c": [np.nan, 6, 7, 8],
    }
)

s = minify(df.to_html(index=False))
print(s)
```

Prints:

```html
<table border=1 class=dataframe><thead><tr style="text-align: right;"><th>a<th>b<th>c<tbody><tr><td>1<td>1<td>NaN<tr><td>1<td>2<td>6.0<tr><td>1<td>3<td>7.0<tr><td>1<td>4<td>8.0</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with pandas alone, but it's easy to post-process the string to remove the newlines and following spaces:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()

out = re.sub(r'\n\s*', '', df.to_html())

print(out)
```

Output:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe"><thead><tr style="text-align: right;"><th></th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody></table>
```